# Handling Null Filters in Elasticsearch Using C#: Allowing Any Color as a Default

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

How to ignore filters that are null in Elasticsearch using C#? For example, if Searchcolor == null, then any color should be allowed .

i used this method :

```
` queryContainerDescriptor.Bool(b => b.Must(
            bQ => bQ.MultiMatch(
                m => m.Fields( f => f.Field(pI => pI.Name, boost: 3)
                                     .Field(pI => pI.ProductSeller)
                                     .Field(pI => pI.ProductBrand)))
            ).Must( bQ => bQ.Range(r => r.Field(pI => pI.Price)
                                         .GreaterThanOrEquals(filter.MinPrice)
                                         .LessThanOrEquals(filter.MaxPrice))
                     ).Must(bQ => bQ.Term(t => t.Field(pI => pI.ProductBrand).Value(filter.ProductBrand))
                     ).Must(bQ => bQ.Term(t => t.Field(pI => pI.ProductType).Value(filter.ProductType))
                     ));`
```